# grandfather clock annoying neighbour

Tags: sounds

I own a grandfather clock that goes off on the quarter (westminster quarters). My neighbour hates being able to hear it all night, which is understandable. My problem is i cant move this clock elsewhere as he is still able to hear it, and i am not going to 'just not wind it' as it holds significant sentimental value to me.

I have tried to negotiate to no avail. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Does it have a *separate* weight to power the chimes? You could simply not wind *that* one up. Or maybe there is a lever inside to disable the chimes.

Comment: Some movements do have a setting which chimes only during the day. Having a similar clock myself, though, I can attest that if you aren't actively paying attention you mostly stop hearing it after a few weeks, except at a mostly-subconscious level. If the neighbor is determined to complain, though, running it silent part or all of the time may be the only way to satisfy them... At which point you need to decide who you would rather satisfy.

Comment: Some people are more sensitive to sounds than others, so the neighbor may not be determined, just desperate.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of the clock and/or mechanism might help.

Comment: Is your neighbors house attached or separate? "i have tried to negotiate to no avail. does anyone have any thoughts?" Negotiate what? So long as it's on your property... Being a nice neighbor is good and neighborly but you have no requirement to do anything about the clock. Authorities would laugh at this and it's a waste of their time. If you want to be nice, you could open up the wall behind the clock, install sound deadening material and close it back up. Could also apply the sound deadening material to the surface of the wall but if it's a nice clock, this will take away from the look.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like the clock chiming but want to dampen the sound adding a piece of foam tape to the end of each of the chime rods or adjust the hammer throw so they don't strike as hard. I have a grandmother wall clock that has a bar to limit the hammer throw that did reduce the sound but not enough in our new very small home. I then added some foam double stick tape to the end of each rod because I had it available. The tape worked well but I had to make sure i put the same amount on each rod or it shifted the frequency and some notes sounded flat. Once I figured it out it only took about a 1/4" of the tape on the end of each rod and now it is enjoyable again.